# Get currently playing video in Youtube

Tags: firefox, video, youtube, youtube-api

I need to get the title of the currently playing video in my Firefox browser from an external app using youtube API, or at least my last played video in my YT account. The goal is to get the name of the song i'm listening to and putting it in a file. I've got another app (using Discord API) that will read it and use it.

My first idea was to get the watch history, but this function was removed from the API since late 2016.

I managed to authentificate my Google application to access my own channel with Oauth 2.0, but from here I'm stuck. There don't seem to be any request that gets your own last watched video.

I also thought of a completely different way, by using a Firefox extension to get the title, but storing it and passing it to the other app will not be an easy thing (localStorage and sessionStorage are both in AppData folder, and my other app can't access it).

Does anybody know a way to do this? I'm starting to be kind of desperate.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and came across this in my search: [Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)

Sharing cookies between 2 applications via a 3rd party might be of help here although it would complicate things.